# Prevent Array Linebreaks in Console output (Visual Studio Code; Node.js)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, command, line-breaks

I would like to change the settings of how many characters or elements of my array are shown before the line breaks.
This happens for some reason after 6 elements:

```
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

This will result in the following output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[
  1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 7
]
```

However, I would prefer the following output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

Does anyone know, how I can change these settings?
When I tried to google it, there were all kind of suggestions about in-code line breaks and general logging, but I could not find anyone with this issue.

Hope this is a no brainer.
Thanks in advance.
Br, Till

Comment: Check this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72210#issuecomment-502713543

Comment: @marekful: Thank you for your comment. I just tried it, and it does not change anything for the Array-Output as far as I can see with my examples. Any other ideas?